# SwiftUI - Value of type 'some View' has no member 'resizable'

Tags: ios, swiftui, resizable, xcode14

I'm new to SwiftUI coding and trying to learn step by step.
Sometimes I don't get what XCode is trying to tell me with its errors.
Following a super simple tutorial on how to resize an image.
Did everything ok until this error came up:

Value of type 'some View' has no member 'resizable'

I'm trying to resize an image in my assets folder.
This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

...
...

 var body: some View {

...

 Image("home_illustration")
                        .padding(.bottom,60)
                        .resizable()
...

 }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each SwiftUI modifier returns a type. The final type of a `View`'s `body` can be extremely complex, hence the existence of `some View` - that basically tells the compiler that you're returning something that conforms to the `View` protocol, but that you don't have the time or the energy to spell out exactly what it is, and anyway that's your job, you're a compiler, just figure it out.

Some modifiers only make sense when applied to certain types of view. In your case, `.padding` can be added to anything, so it's a method on the `View` protocol. It returns a type of `ModifiedContent<SwiftUI.Image, SwiftUI._PaddingLayout>`. These types build up the more modifiers you apply.

`.resizable()` is a method on `Image`, which returns an `Image`.

So if you resize, then pad the image, you're OK. If you apply padding, you aren't dealing with an image any more, so the compiler can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It's really important to find out more about how things work!

Answer (score 4):

you have to use `.resizable()` above the .padding and below the Image. The reason is `Image with padding is create a new child view` so we can't apply .resizable() to view. It is for Image only. Let me know if you are not clear with my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As wrote in my self-post, I've found out about playing randomly with the modifiers, but your answer is definitely teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution randomly by playing with my code.
The problem was the order of the modifiers.

"resizable()" should be always first.

Don't ask me why but...it just works.
Hopefully, this will help others.

Comment: Resizable only works on an image, once padding is applied it is “some View” not an image